# How to set NULL to entity field in UPDATE query?

Tags: hibernate

How to set a ManyToOne property to NULL width HQL ?

```
UPDATE ErpTrace RCD set RCD.stkStore=NULL

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns at
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is OneToMany/ManyToOne relation, you can do this by remove the RCD.id at stkSotre entity.
if this is ManyToMany relation, just remove the record in the middle table.

Comment: i know thanks, i finally choose that way, but its not normal that HQL dosn't handle component in update queries, its a bug to me